# Ajax.ActionLink takes to a different Page MVC 4.5 Visual studio 2015

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

i checked all possible stackoverflow and asp.net questions about this subject and couldnt solve my problem.
As the title says my Ajax.ActionLink Redirects to a new page instead of replacing the div i selected. i have loaded all necessary packages
see my code below:
 in my Bundles i have this:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                    "~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax"));
```

In Bottom of _Layout page

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/lib")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

View

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink("New User", "New", "Person", new AjaxOptions
{
UpdateTargetId = "userTable",
HttpMethod = "GET",
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
OnFailure = "Something unexpected has occured"
},new {@class = "btn btn-primary"})

<div id="usersTable">
@Html.Partial("_UserTable")
</div>

@section scripts {...} // Some code to load the table on existing partial that is beeing rendered
```

New action in Person controller

```
  public PartialViewResult New()
    {
        var person = new Person();
        return PartialView("_UserForm", person);
    }
```

PLEASE HELP i have been going on this for days now and honestly i have tried almost everything posted out there.

Edit 1: As a response to jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js is not loaded correctly, or perhaps being overwritten i have included the browser scripts as they are loaded on the page

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/bootbox.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/datatables/jquery.datatables.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/datatables/datatables.bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/toastr.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
```

Comment: It means that `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` is not loaded correctly, or perhaps being overwritten (e.g. you might have loaded a copy of `jquery-{version}.js` after you have loaded `bundles/jqueryval`)

Comment: You do not have `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` in that list  - its not loaded at all :)

Comment: Hah thanks guys. I would have never spotted it men a day wasted for no reason!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax"));
```

shouldn't it be this?

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*",
                "~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"));
```

The .js file extension is missing.